# Gutenberg block show something when element is selected

Tags: reactjs, jsx, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm building a Gutenberg block and am trying to show an input when an element is selected.

```
    <RichText
        tagName="a"
        className="button"
        placeholder={ __( 'Text...' ) }
        keepPlaceholderOnFocus={ true }
        value={ text }
        onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { text: value } ) }
    />                      
   { isSelected && (

        <form
            className="inline-input"
            onSubmit={ ( event ) => event.preventDefault() }>
            <URLInput
            value={ URL }
            onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { URL: value } ) }
         />
        </form>
  ) }
```

When the element with class name "button" is selected the form should show. Instead, the form shows from the start. Am I using isSelected wrong?

Comment: Could you post the full block code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still learning REACT for Gutenberg/Block Editor. But I've managed to come up with a workaround for this.

You need to use an `IF` conditional for the element (shorthand). You can use the className `hidden` to show/hide an element.

```
 <form
        className={ !your_attribute ? "hidden" : "inline-input" }
        onSubmit={ ( event ) => event.preventDefault() }>
        <URLInput
        value={ URL }
        onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { URL: value } ) }
     />
    </form>
```

The `isSelected` is used if the user has clicked on the block to make it "active". You can probably use states in this case as well. I just find this will keep the form showing if the user selected the button and then saves their post/page.

As mentioned, I'm still learning REACT + Gutenberg/Block Editor. I hope this helps.

Comment: Replace `your_attribute` with the attribute you are saving if it's clicked. So something like "show_form".